# Font-face not displaying on Chrome

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

http://www.milknhny.co.uk/

I have a fontface call on my `CSS` for the above, but for a bizarre thing its not displaying on chrome at my work, yet works at home!

My call is :

```
@font-face {
 font-family: Bazar;
 src: url(http://www.milknhny.co.uk/fonts/Bazar.ttf);
 src: url(http://www.milknhny.co.uk/fonts/Bazar.eot);
 src: url(http://www.milknhny.co.uk/fonts/Bazar.svg);
 src: url(http://www.milknhny.co.uk/fonts/Bazar.woff);
 }
```

Any ideas why it wouldnt be working on my chrome, as i thought by calling all the above that it would be suitable cross browser.

thanks

Update:- The below fixed the chrome problem... however still not working in IE... any ideas?

Comment: I get an error 404 when i try to go directly to those font files in the browser. Recommended usage for font face here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: Hi Billy,Its ok i sorted it, basically i had not referenced it with ' ' between the URL etc. Its working fine now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably had not actually uploaded the font files. This seems to have caused a redirection and then a 404 Not Found response from a server. (The initial problem was a malformed `@font-face` rule, which you fixed in your answer.)

The problem seems to have been fixed now.

Comment: Hi Jukka, Thanks for this, it appears that for some bizarre reason it still doesnt like the custom fonts in IE.... hmmm

Comment: What’s missing in IE? It seems that in the right hand bar, the declared custom font OpenSansCondBold is not used. It’s defined in a `@font-face referring to a TTF font only, and IE does not support TTF for downloadable fonts. Declare WOFF and (for old IE’s) EOT, too.

Comment: Hi Jukka, Ignore the OpenSans. Im refering to the Bazar font. I know ive yet to sort out the others via Font Squirrel.... if u look at the below surely it should be within IE as ive done all the calls to suggest this? However it isnt? Doesnt it work in certain versions of IE?

Comment: Hi Kirsty, it seems that http://www.milknhny.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Milk%20N%20Hunney/fonts/bazar.eot is missing (the browser gets a redirection to an HTML page, not a font). This explains why Bazar does not work on IE 8 and earlier. I suppose it’s just the location or protection of the bazar.eot font on the server.

Comment: ah right! ok... this is making sense now! Its because i put all the fonts at the beginning! ie website.com/fonts/...... I will copy and move them, because its bizarre how its finding the rest and not that one lol!

Comment: Jukka your a diamond, it appears that is the problem. I have been putting the fonts in the fonts folder in my main public_html rather than directly in the theme folder/fonts. I have since done a copy and its corrected one of the fonts in IE. The one with all the calls on it. So i will just do the rest on Font Squirrel and it should work :) Thankyou again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by doing the below: (slight changes)

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Bazar';
src: url('fonts/bazar.eot');
src: url('fonts/bazar.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/bazar.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/bazar.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/bazar.svg#bazarmedium') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

thanks anyways :D

Comment: try http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator It generates a stylesheet next to fonts. You can even set some options. All stylesheets I used from there worked very good. Even better is http://compass-style.org/ it prevents you from typing the same over and over again, copy and pasting what is a potential source of mistakes

Comment: Hi Phillip the above code is what I have generated from font squirrel but it still not working, maybe it's the browser at work because surely all chrome works the same depending on if u have a plugin or sumthing